# Is it possible to encode URL of jdbc connection string?

Tags: url, jdbc, sonarqube, encode

Am using one of the in-house automation tools to fill the configuration file. Because of some issues with the tool, I had to encode the URL string value:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://<server>:3306/sonar_db?useUnicode=true%26characterEncoding=utf8%26rewriteBatchedStatements=true%26useConfigs=maxPerformance
```

But when I am doing this, getting exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection property 'useUnicode' only
>   accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value
>   'true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance'
>   is not in this set.)

Comment: I don't see how you are 'encoding' anything. To me it simply looks like you in-house tool doesn't properly parse things. And without the code used, it would be blind guessing. You might get it working by separating by a semi-colon (`;`) instead, but that is assuming everything after `?` is blindly passed to the DBCP config property `connectionProperties` (also make sure to include a closing `;`)

Comment: sorry about this, my jdbc uri was wrong, i have updated it.

Comment: If this is a properties file that is read by `Properties` or `ResourceBundle` you should use a backslash to escape the `=`. The server won't understand `%26` as you want. Get the tool fixed if there really is a problem with it, which doesn't seem likely.

Comment: thanks guys, i had to finally fix this in the tool itself, couldn't find any other alternative

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace `&`/`%26` with `&amp;` ?